# Defining CSS properties twice

Tags: css

general.css

```
#feedback_bar
{
  /*props*/
}
```

another.css

```
#feedback_bar
{
  /*props*/
}
```

Is this allowed? Will both get inherited?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The properties defined last will override properties defined previously. Unless you use `!important` on the previously defined section of CSS.

```
.thing {
    padding: 10px;
}

.thing {
    padding: 12px;
}
```

`.thing` will have `padding: 12px;`

```
.thing {
    padding: 15px !important;
}

.thing {
    padding: 123px;
}
```

`.thing` will have `padding: 15px;`

This is allowed, and to more strictly answer your question, both will indeed be inherited as shown by this example:

```
.thing {
    padding: 10px;
}

.thing {
    background: red;
}
```

`.thing` will have both `padding: 10px;` and `background: red;`.

Also, please take a moment to read some of the comments on this answer as they raise good points worth further reading.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `!important` is intended to be a diagnostic tool--not a solution to sloppy CSS.

Comment: @Shango - I also often use `!important` to deal with JS (out-of-my-control) modifying inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

The one that is loaded last overwrites the previous declaration(s). As for being allowed, css cannot throw errors at you :P. Probably not a good idea though.

Comment: Indeed, but I like the idea of not rendering a page with errors in style or markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed, but if there are duplicate properties, the last one will be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is common, and which style wins depends on [the Cascade. Selectors are scored in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), and the selector with the highest score wins. You can think of the score like, an ID gets 100, a class gets 10, and a tag gets 1 - but read the CSS definition for the details:

```
#myId: Score 100
.myClass: Score 10
p.myClass: Score 11
.class1.class2.class3: Score 30
#myId.myClass: Score 110
```

If the selectors are identical as you had above, then the one that loads last wins.

You can think of !important as adding 1000, so:

```
#myId {
  color: #000; Score 100

#myId {
  color: #000 !important; Score 1100
```

Thus the !important winning here, even if it comes first. And again if both have !important, you get matching scores, the last one loaded wins again.

The MozDev link above explains the Cascade and Selector Scoring well, but you can also read the more obtuse [definition in the CSS spec itself](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/).