# Can you use 2 :before pseudo classes in the same div?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Lets say I have:

```
<div class="container">
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

would I be able to use 2 :before pseudo classes in that same container div?

like so:

```
  .container:before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 31%;
    height: 61%;
    background-color: black;
  }

.container:before{
    content: " A String ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

Ignore the actual css but the question here is would that be valid inserting 2 pseudo classes before that container div? and if not is there a way that it can be?

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know?

Comment: Well I tried and it did not come out correctly but I ask because there may be something someone knows that can make it work or some info on that.. Just getting more info on people with experience with that pseudo class.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065958/defining-css-properties-twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use two `:before` instanced in a single element. Here is a non-working jsfiddle, which makes use of two :`before` instances on a single `div`. As you can see, the second `:before` statement overrides the first one's styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/Luwhf700/

Now, here, we have a working one, using `:before` and `:after`, which would be similar to using two `:before` statements (only for absolute positioning elements).

http://jsfiddle.net/Luwhf700/1/

Comment: I see ok thanks, just out of curiosity on that jsfiddle you used left:auto and it positioned the div all the way to the rite. why is that? what did auto do to left?

Comment: I used `left: auto` for the first case, where two `:before` uses didn't work. If we remove `left: auto` from the second `:before` use, it will inherit `left: 0` from the first :before use, and `right: 0` won't work to position the element to the right. So, I am resetting the left value with `left: auto`, so I can position the element to the right. If this answer helped, can you please vote up and / or mark as correct answer?

Comment: so left: auto positions the elements as if it were to be right:0; ?

Comment: No, I used `left: auto` just to reset the `left: 0` which was applied to the first `:before` I used. As you can see, in the second `:before`, I've used `right: 0`, but if we don't add `left: auto, it won't be position to the right, because `left` will have the value of `0`, from the upper `:before`. I hope I am clear. If not, you can make a new question, and I can add a more detailed answer to it.

Comment: Ahh I see ok now I understand. Thanks a ton Amar appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done, since the css is overwritten, you can [see the same here](http://prntscr.com/6t0eyc) Also [Amar Syla answered the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29595207/2196341)

***if not is there a way that it can be?***

You can use java script/ jquery to add a `class` or an `id` to the div based on your condition and the set the css.

For example:

```
#before1.container{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-color: red;
  }

#before.container{
    content: " A String ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

Then you just need to set the `id` like below, using jquery/javascript

```
<div id="before" class="container">
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>


<div id="before1" class="container">
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

To know how to set `div id` dynamically, [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514924/dynamically-setting-div-id-in-javascript-or-jquery) It has both java script and jquery solutions

Comment: Thanks for the answer appreciate it!